# Array Push a Multi Dimentional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

trying to add the array below into an existing one with **array_push**:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'and',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'national'
            )
    )
```

the existing array:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',       
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'events_start-date',
                'value' => date('YYYY-mm-dd'),
                'type' => 'CHAR',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
);
```

i have tried this code with no luck:

```
array_push(
$args, array('tax_query'=> array('relation' => 'and', 
array('taxonomy' => 'prince-range','field' => 'slug','terms' => '99')
)));
```

Comment: what "didn't work" means?

Comment: didn't merged the array

Comment: so the array left the same?

Comment: I took your code and copy-pasted it: http://ideone.com/y1cASZ The result is desired, but it did merge array. Does that mean that you haven't even run your code?

Comment: It doesn't merge the array as needed. it needs to be in it's own index as Phillip has mentioned. Thanks for your help @zerkms

Comment: he provided a hardcoded solution, which will require modification on every array structure change. Compare to my answer.

Comment: @zerkms this is the result I was after http://pastebin.com/0eRRN5Zc it's own index?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re over complicating it.

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
     'relation' => 'and',
          array(
               'taxonomy' => 'type',
               'field' => 'slug',
               'terms' => 'national'
         )
     );
```

Comment: What if you already have existing array you want to merge to the current?

Comment: This will merge them.  It’ll add the new data to an array key called `tax_query` automatically.

Comment: what if you just have `$array_to_append`? Where did you get `tax_query` string from? Why do you think it is hardcoded?

Comment: That will add it to the end of the array with the next available numeric array key (keys start at 0 in PHP).

Comment: you didn't get my point. Read the question once again and answer: why do you think `tax_query` is hardcoded in your code?

Comment: it's not, but my question is still here: what if the array to merge is dynamic. How would you know `tax_query`?

Comment: Thank you Phillip, you're completely right! I was over complicating it... this works excellent.

Comment: @zerkms, depends on the situation of course.  You could easily substitute another `$args[’$variable’]` if you wanted, but in this case the array to be added was named `tax_query` so I answered the question based on that.

Comment: `You could easily substitute another $args[’$variable’]` --- what if there are more than one items in array? :-S I agree the question is asked *terribly*, but it's too specific answer :-S

Comment: Guysm thanks for your help both, i appreciate it. sorry my question wasn't clear

Comment: @zerkms: What if the sky is falling? You deal with each situation as it arises.

Comment: @Phillip: assuming that an array will always have some key as soon as you just need a merge is weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
$merged = array_merge($args, $array_to_merge);
```

As soon as you're merging 2 arrays - you need to use `array_merge`, not `array_push`

Online demo: http://ideone.com/jHQipV

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'and',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'national'
            )
    )
);

$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',       
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'events_start-date',
                'value' => date('YYYY-mm-dd'),
                'type' => 'CHAR',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
);

$args[] = $arr;
```

var_dump on `$args`:

```
array(3) { ["post_type"]=> string(6) "events" ["meta_query"]=> array(2) { ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" [0]=> array(4) { ["key"]=> string(17) "events_start-date" ["value"]=> string(26) "2013201320132013-0505-2929" ["type"]=> string(4) "CHAR" ["compare"]=> string(2) ">=" } } [0]=> array(1) { ["tax_query"]=> array(1) { ["relation"]=> array(3) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(4) "type" ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["terms"]=> string(8) "national" } } } }
```